# Error with googlesheets package in R - unable to load curl

Tags: r, rcurl, r-googlesheets

I'm trying to update a google sheet in R using the googlesheets package, but:

whenever I try **gs_title('Name_of_the_sheet')**, I get an error saying ***'Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’'.***

Of course, I tried installing the package curl before calling the package using the library function:

**install.packages('curl')**

When i install curl, it says : **"package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked"**

followed by:

*"Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘curl’"*

And when I use "library('curl')", I get: "Error in library("curl") : there is no package called ‘curl’"

I've also tried:

- 'install.packages(c('devtools','curl'))'
- using'gs_url' & 'gs_ls' instead of 'gs_title'
- closing all R sessions

. But again, that's of no use.

I want to be able to update the google sheet without running into this error. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Your package will have a folder name in the location:

***C:\Users\Username\Documents\R\win-library\3.5***

Delete that folder; then try installing the package and load it. That would solve this problem.